# Why won't Kaspersky scan past 1%?

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, kaspersky

I renewed my program and now I seem to be having problems with the scanning. It seems to update with no problems but not scan? I removed it and re installed per the Kas web site and it still isnt working. Can someone here help me?
Thanks

Comment: With all my respect, guess it is better to ask KAV support about this

Comment: Like i said, i did that, they suggested re-installing, which i did and it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose there is an outside chance it's a filesystem error that's killing the scan, try doing chkdsk /r on your c drive and see if that helps.  If not it may be that you've picked up something nasty that's killing kaspersky and you might want to try running the scan from safe mode.

Answer (score 1):

There's one other obvious possibility...you're infected by a virus that is actively causing Kaspersky to fail. I'd suggest downloading a second virus scanner, running that to see what happens (Make sure to uninstall afterwords...the only thing that slows your PC down more than an antivirus is TWO antivirus apps)

Answer (score 1):

error check and defrag your hard drive.  it may be stuck on a corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

1. The scanned item simply takes a long time to scan. This can happen if, for example, if an enormous zip file contains many items to be checked, or if an enormous file, such as an .iso, needs to be scanned for "patterns".
2. The scan threshold is too inclusive and inoffensive files like .txt are also being scanned.
3. The percentage calculation may be false, and this 1% represents rather a large chunk of the disk.
4. A bug in Kaspersky, so wait for the next version or find another product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully remember what the XP interface looks like anymore (been on & a while), but I had the problem where it scans 1 or 2 files (1%), then simply hangs and the time remaining climbs into #days. Closing Kaspersky and running it in compatibility for XP SP2 with Admin rights enabled solved the problem for me.

I'm not sure whether something like this would work for you, but it's worth mentioning I hope.